# Try to read a request body with a stream i get System.InvalidOperationException (readtimeout,writetimeout properties)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I try to read a request body from an HttpActionExecutedContext context because i want to log exceptions(.net framework).
In several posts the solution is a method like

```
private string GetBodyFromRequest(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            string data;
            using (var stream = context.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
            {
                if (stream.CanSeek)
                {
                    stream.Position = 0;
                }
                data = context.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            return data;
        }
```

or like

```
private async Task<string> GetBodyAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            string request;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var requestStream = await context.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                requestStream.Position = 0;
                requestStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                {
                    request = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return request;
        }
```

But the problem is that the return string is empty because in these lines

```
using (var stream = context.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
```

and

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
```

i have System.InvalidOperationException in

> ReadTimeout

,

> WriteTimeout

properties when i debug it,but not throw exception that stops the program,only return empty string.

Comment: You don't have to block the `async` operation by calling a `Result` here `ReadAsStreamAsync().Result`

Comment: but in the second implementation have the same problem in line var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()